# Xamarin iOS cant get a specific variable from a PushNotification Payload

Tags: c#, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios, nsdictionary

By sending the following APNS-Payload:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"test Push","badge":1,"sound":"default"},
"objid":"SomeID","vid":"4229", "title":"aTitle","type":"queryform", 
"idArray":["-100", "SomeID"]}`
```

The following method converts the NSDictionary to a class(notificationInfo is the userInfo from "receivedNotification".
Following problem: if the ObjectForKey:"idArray" to get the "idArray" is equal the key in the payload, the variable `objid` is null. But `objid` exists in the notificationInfo. If I rename "idArray" e.g. to `Idarray`, `objid` would be set.

```
    ApnsNotificationInfo GetApnsNotificationInfo(NSDictionary notificationInfo)
    {

        var apnsInfo = new ApnsNotificationInfo();

        if (notificationInfo == null || notificationInfo.Count == 0)
            return apnsInfo;

        var idArray = notificationInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("idArray")) as NSArray;

        if (idArray != null && idArray.Count > 0)
        {
            var articleId = (idArray.Count == 2) ? 
                idArray.GetItem<NSNumber>(1) : 
                idArray.GetItem<NSNumber>(0);

            if (articleId == null)
                return apnsInfo;

            apnsInfo.ArticleId = articleId.Int32Value;

            if (idArray.Count == 2)
            {
                var categoryId = idArray.GetItem<NSNumber>(0);

                if (categoryId != null)
                    apnsInfo.CategoryId = categoryId.Int32Value;
            }

        }

        NSString message = null;

        var aps = notificationInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;

        if (aps != null)
            message = aps.ObjectForKey(new NSString("alert")) as NSString;

        if (message != null)
            apnsInfo.Message = message.ToString();

        var title = notificationInfo.ObjectForKey (new NSString ("title")) as NSString;
        var type = notificationInfo.ObjectForKey (new NSString ("type")) as NSString;
        var objid = notificationInfo.ObjectForKey (new NSString ("objid")) as NSString;
        var vid = notificationInfo.ValueForKey (new NSString ("vid")) as NSString;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty (title)){
            apnsInfo.Title = title;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (type)) {

            apnsInfo.Type = type;

            if(objid != null){

                apnsInfo.requestID = objid.ToString ();
            }
            if(vid != null){
                apnsInfo.vid =  Convert.ToInt32 (vid);
            }
        }
        return apnsInfo;
    }
```

Another explanation for my problem: if i send this payload:
`{"aps":{"alert":"test Push","badge":1,"sound":"default"}, "objid":"SomeID","vid":"4229", "title":"aTitle","type":"queryform", "Idarray":["-100", "SomeID"]}`

```
    var objid = notificationInfo.ObjectForKey (new NSString ("objid")) as NSString;
```

`objid` would be set. If the array in the payload is called: `idArray`, `objid = null`

This is really weird. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

So although I don't entirely understand your question, as you said yourself you can solve the problem by pulling out 'objid' directly, there are a few things that need to be amended in your payload and your code to adhere to best practices.

The payload I believe should be as follows: (You miss some defining brackets after objid, and at the end of the idArray).

```
{"aps":{"alert":"test Push","badge":1,"sound":"default"},
"objid":{"SomeID","vid":"4229", "title":"aTitle","type":"queryform", 
"idArray":["-100", "SomeID"]}}
```

Also your code is not using null propagation correctly, and will cause you issues in the future. if your checking for null, you must also propogate the Count otherwise it will likely cause an exception to be thrown.

```
 if (idArray != null && idArray?.Count > 0)
 {
 }
```

It's also worth noting that often JSON deserialises property names in lower case. This can differ between deserialisers however.

Comment: Thank you, but the Point is following: if i write in the payload "idArray" objid will not be set, if i write "idarray"(or delete "idArray") objid will be set.